# Ask gcc to print error locations without dir, just the filename

Tags: gcc

How to make gcc print error locations **without the directory name**,
using just the filename itself. For example, instead of:

```
$ gcc input.c
/home/oren/some/very/very/long/dir/input.c: error exponent has no digits
```

This:

```
$ gcc input.c
input.c: error exponent has no digits
```

Comment: You cannot. Why would you want that? Of course you can pass just the filename to gcc, which means you have to invoke it from the directory of that file.

Comment: I use a screen shot of the compilation output in a slide show. The exact location is irrelevant, and since it's too long, it wraps around the terminal four times ...

Comment: This is rather unusual, I have never seen gcc doing that. Normally it uses the exact filename you pass it as an argument. What gcc version and OS are you using?

Comment: @n.m. you are completely right -- the compilation line is called from a makefile with absolute filename which caused all this trouble. Thanks!